# Android Studio : "Error: Could not find or load main class"

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using Android Studio for around a couple of weeks without any issues so far. But recently , I've started getting this error when I try to open Android Studio. I use Ubuntu 16.10.

```
Tools/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Error: Could not find or load main class #
```

What am I doing wrong ? I've tried re-extracting android studio again. Still the same.

Comment: Try using Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK

Comment: Tried switching to Oracle JDK. Unfortunately , still the same.

Answer (score 8):

Some of your android studio configuration files are probably messed up. To fix this delete  `.android` `.AndroidStudio` (might have a version number eg. `.AndroidStudio2.3/`).
To save time for beginners, they maybe directories and can to deleted using

```
rm -rf ~/.AndroidStudio*
rm -rf ~/.android*
```

PS: It  makes sense to have a backup of every configuration file your use using a version control. saves me time and energy.
[Based on this](https://askubuntu.com/a/560617)

Comment: For those wondering, those .AndroidStudio and .android directories should be in your home folder: cd ~

Comment: Deleting those directories worked for me: open a terminal, `cd /home/yourname/` then `rm .AndroidStudio -R` and `rm .android -R` then open AS again.

Answer (score 0):

Either the file  `<your_installation_path>/android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar`

does not exist or has the wrong ownership.

Because the installation is located in your home directory, execute the following command that will give your user ownership:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <your_installation_path>/android-studio/
```

If that does not work, check if the file `android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar` exists. If not, then download and extract the archive again.

Answer (score 0):

###### It can be solved by deleting `.idea` and `.gradle` folders from your project root.