# Android studio: Error: Could not find or load main class Main

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying out to run my first Java only application in Android studio and it is throwing me an error on my Mac with the following error: 
Error: Could not find or load main class Main

I have tried all the different possibilities like I have removed android cache files; removed old android studio and installed the new one but still same issue.

I have tried to follow this link: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41791674/android-studio-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class) but its still the same issue.

Has anyone tried any other solution to figure this out and found a solution ?

Comment: Shot in the dark, maybe try and run a Gradle build task once first.

Comment: I am also struggling. Please let us know if a solution is available for android studio.

Comment: I finally got it working by removing the project from Android studio and it rebuilt. Dont know what could have been going wrong but what try out what bboll suggested by running gradle build task.